Syntax error on creating trigger function in PostgreSQL
I use the next script to create trigger function in PostgreSQL:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pdate_day_month_decade_trigger()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW."dayMonth" <> OLD."dayMonth" THEN
        DECLARE decadeMonthValue INTEGER := (
            CASE
              WHEN NEW."dayMonth" >= 1 AND NEW."dayMonth" <= 10 THEN 1
              WHEN NEW."dayMonth" >= 11 AND NEW."dayMonth" <= 20 THEN 2
              ELSE 3
            END
         );
         UPDATE main."YDate"
         SET "decadeMonth"=decadeMonthValue
         WHERE id = NEW.id;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$

But got an error:
ERROR:  syntax error (at or near: "SET")
LINE 16:    SET "decadeMonth"=decadeMonthValue
            ^
CONTEXT:  wrong type name "main."YDate"
         SET "decadeMonth"" 

ОШИБКА:  syntax error (at or near: "SET")
SQL state: 42601
Character: 394

I tried to change syntax of types (used full names and shortened), but error still persists.

The plpgsql block structure isn't respected. DECLARE should occur before BEGIN. While not needed here, you could nest several blocks into each others, but their structure must still be respected.

Thanks it helped, also I removed redundant variable declaration.
